# rails tenancy / default route-to-view mapping / same controllers, different views path issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails

let's use a routes posts_controllers#index

Using acts_as_tenant, a view path is prepended at top level in before_action :

```
def set_view_path!
  append_view_path(Rails.root.join("app/views/#{tenant.slug}"))
end
```

Instead of :

```
- app
   - views
     - posts
        - index.html
```

we aim at :

```
- app
   - views
     - {tenant_slug}
        - posts
          - index.html
```

It almost works, but an empty method is needed :

```
class PostsController
  def index
  end
end
```

rails wont default-map to the view in `app/views/{tenant_slug}/posts/index.html.erb` without the empty method, it invariably ends up with `AbstractController::ActionNotFound` if the empty method is not specified

Is it possible to avoid the need of the empty method, while still being able to correctly retrieve the tenant based view ?

Comment: Do you want to use rails as MV framework? you said that rails `would match the action to the view without the need to specify the method in the controller`, but action is the method, and rails defines rendering view by controller's name and action. If you don't want `dex index` inside PostsController -> create `def index` in the ApplicationController

Comment: hi @AntonBogdanov, i've edited a bit; hope it clarifies

Answer (score 0):

looks like this will work

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  before_action :set_custom_path

  private

  def set_custom_path
    prepend_view_path "app/views/#{tenant.slug}"
  end
end
```

And you will not need to specify custom views in every action.

Comment: partially. `class PostsController; def index; end; end` will find `app/views/{tenant_slug}/posts/index.html.erb`, but `class PostsController; end` won't. I meant above that, by standard, you're not required to specify the controller method as long as the view exists. In that config, you're required to specify and empty action for the controller's action to match the corresponding view

Comment: you must have action, even 1 line of code `def index; end`, if you don't like action in this controller -> add the same action to ApplicationController

Comment: not that i like it or not; but my question is about why, in that context, we *must* have it; as it is not needed in a default context

Comment: rails router calls controller's action. action renders view, you said `you're not required to specify the controller method as long as the view exists.` - but this is totally wrong, for rendering some view you must have 1 line in route, 3 lines in controller and empty view file

Comment: nope. here : `class PostsController; def index; end; end`, the `def index; end` is not mandatory as long as the view exists (at least as of rails 7). so we're fine with a bare minimum of 1 line in route, an `class PostsController; end` (empty) controller, and an empty view file. rails glues the route straight to the view as long as you simply named a controller. no surprises as the conventions are strong enough to permit. But this default automagical behaviour disappears in this custom tenant context described here; so i'm asking